# What if natives of the Far Realms ignored the wild magic trait?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, magic, planes, wild-magic

According to the *Manual of The Planes* the Far Realm (312) has the planar trait [wild magic](http://dndsrd.net/planes.html#table-wild-magic-effects):

> Any spell or spell-like ability used on a wild magic plane has a chance to go awry. The caster must make a level check (DC 15 + the level of the spell or effect) for the magic to function normally. For spell-like abilities, use the level or HD of the creature employing the ability for the caster level check and the level of the spell-like ability to set the DC for the caster level check.
>
> Failure on this check means that something strange happens…. (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 149)

A failure on this caster level check sees a spell or spell-like ability fail or worse about 2/3 of the time and be cast normally or a little better or a little worse about 1/3 of the time.

Natives of the Far Realms can include, for example, [aboleths](http://dndsrd.net/monstersA.html#aboleth) (*Monster Manual* 8–9) that, in addition to their psionic spell-like abilities can be powerful casters. Such creatures would seem to be at a *severe* disadvantage on their native plane.

How would  game balance be affected if creatures native to a plane that possesses the planar trait wild magic *ignored* that planar trait while on their own plane?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I'm not sure this question's currently a good fit for the site as it sounds ultimately like an opinion question, as in *Should natives of planes that possess the wild magic trait still make wild magic rolls?* The site *can't* know if that's appropriate for *your* campaign. Instead, the site *can* answer a more direct question, like *How would game balance be affected if wild magic planes' natives didn't make wild magic checks?* (You're welcome to edit this question to say that, by the way!) Anyway, no matter what, thank you for participating and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Wild Magic is not normal magic. The miscastings are a result of the magic being unstable, not that the caster isn't proficient. However, a wild magic mage can gain wisdom in how to better control the wild magic.

In short, there is a chance that the magic does something other than what you want it to do. It is not that the caster has miscast but rather that the magic decided to do something else.